# activeadmin default_actions edit one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hi I'm working with ruby on rails, active admin and I have a table with several columns, my question is: can I allow to edit only one of those columns? I want that the user just can change one, without having acces to edit neither delete the other columns. Is it possible?

```
 actions :all, :except => [:destroy]  
 ..........
 index do
   selectable_column
   ...........
   ..............
   end
   default_actions :name => "Actions"
 end
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you ok with a edit form with just that one column to edit?

Comment: Do you mean if I like the way it edits now? yes I like, but the point is that now it also allows to edit the other columns, and that is what i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the form to be shown for editing

```
  index do
    ....
  end
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Some heading" do
      if f.object.persisted?
        #is shown when editing an existing object
        f.input :field1
      else
        #is shown when creating a new object
        f.input :field1
        f.input :field2
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Will only render the form with the fields that you have added.